# Preg Match Spaces & New Lines?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code

```
$pattern = '#\bset_message\("(.*?)"\)#';
$found = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

But if my $string is

```
set_message("Hello there
I like
to 
eat
CHEES!");
```

it doesn't return anything for matches, but it does if I use

```
set_message("Hello there!");
```

how can I add new lines and stuff like that (\r\n, \n, etc)?

Comment: How can a pattern `\bset_message\("(.*?)"\)` match a string like `"Hello there!"`? There's something missing in your posting. Probably, you'll need to add the `/s` [modifier (PCRE dotall) to your regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)?

Comment: Read the link in my comment above, then you'll understand ([PCRE dotall](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `m` modifier.

```
$pattern = '#\bset_message\("(.*?)"\)#m';
```

When you want that `.` could mean `\n` also, you need to use both `m' and`s` modifiers:

```
$pattern = '#\bset_message\("(.*?)"\)#ms';
```

Comment: For some reason this is still not working... Is there somewhere specific I need to put the `m`? I put it at the end of the line but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: add `s` also, if you want to match newlines; `#...#sm`